# SQL Server how to create correct permissions for users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My scope is the following. I have a database where user must be allowed to make changes on tables. They will run some stored procedures which will copy tables from another database and also create new tables. The users (access through an active directory group) must NOT be able to modify the stored procedures.

To solve this issue I have tried the following:
Create a new schema, which allows the group to execute. I have placed the stored procedures in the schema.
In the schema DBO in the database, I have granted the group access to Alter, Control, Create sequence, delete, Execute, Insert, References, Select, Update.
The stored procedures try to create tables under DBO.

When trying to execute a stored procedure the user is getting the following message:

`Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table 'MyTable', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'mydabase'.`

So my question. Is this the best way to solve this issue and if yes what am I missing to do?

Comment: This is contradictory - if all a user will do is run a stored procedure, then he doesn't need direct permissions to the tables (unless there's some dynamic SQL involved).

Comment: Bottom line is this: On a specific database the users must be able to run stored procedure, create and alter tables, but not be able to alter specific stored procedures. Is it possible to do a setup like this?

Comment: What happens when a user removes a column from a table that's referenced by a stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I have no time to answer it properly right now, sry, but I would instead suggest you read this first (and come back later if there's more questions): http://sommarskog.se/grantperm.html